# How do I activate the bluetooth function on my Ubuntu system if there's “no default controller available” and hciconfig pulls up nothing

Tags: server, bluetooth, raspberrypi

I'm running Ubuntu server 18.04 on a raspberry pi 3 model b but whenever I try to use any of the Bluetooth features of the device, it acts like there are no bluetooth capabilities. Running the `rfkill list` command only brings up settings for the Wireless LAN, not hci0, running the `hciconfig` command brings up nothing at all, and running the `bluetoothctl` command  works but if I try to scan, search for devices, advertise, etc. I just get the message: "No default controller available. I've already tried setting `AutoEnable=true` in the `etc/bluetooth/main.conf` but this has also done nothing. Here's the output for `dmesg | grep Blue`

```
[14.116780] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[14.132786] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[14.142914] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[14.151799] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[14.160984] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Which kernel are you running (output of uname -a), and what is your wireless/bluetooth hardware (outupt of dmesg |egrep -i "wifi|blue|fw|firm"  )?  Look for any "firmware not found messages"

Comment: output of `uname -a`: Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-1027-raspi2 #29~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP... armv71 armv71 GNU/Linux

Comment: Errors from `dmesg |egrep -i "wifi|blue|fw|firm" `: brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: ```Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,3-model-b.txt failed with error -2``` and  `audit: type=1400 audit(1592917106.120:24): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.pi-bluetooth.btuart" name="/dev/ttyAMA0" pid=1654 comm="btattach" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0`. There were five messages like the latter message with just the audit number and pid number being different

Comment: Please add additional requested information to your original question, there you can use the code tags to make it more readable.  Looks like a firmware load failed.  That's the first thing to track down.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution that works: `sudo hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600`
After running this command everything seemed to be fine.